# Find key in multidimensional array and change the value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a PHP script in which I got **a multidimensional array without fixed depth**. Eg:

```
$myArray = [
  'item01' => [
      'section01' => [
        'part01'
      ]
    ],
  'item02' => [
    'section02' => [
      'part02' => [
        'something01'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  'item03' => [
    'section03'
  ]
]
```

I have a string that contains the **path to the value** that should be changed. Eg:

```
$myPath = 'item02/section02/part02'
```

And I have the **new value**:

```
$myValue = 'somethingElse'
```

What I'm trying to do, is go through array $myArray following the path set in $myPath to change the value to $myValue.

The **expected output**, with the examples above, would be this:

```
$myArray = [
  'item01' => [
      'section01' => [
        'part01'
      ]
    ],
  'item02' => [
    'section02' => [
      'part02' => [
        'somethingElse'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  'item03' => [
    'section03'
  ]
]
```

I've tried several ways, but keep getting stumped on this. In the end, it always reaches a point where the solution is, at its core, the same. Rubber duckying didn't help either. Other programmers I know, haven't been able to find a solution either.

I'm hoping someone here can at least provide some fresh ways to look into this.

PS: Everything above is in pseudo-code, as this problem doesn't seem to be language-specific.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That one is for a multidimensional array with fixed depth. All solutions offered in that question won't work with the problem explained here.

Comment: Show your expected output

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: @mega6382 It most certainly did! I'm a bit surprised, as I tried this before too and it didn't work then. I must've made a tiny error somewhere. I'll see what that was after wrapping this up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
$myPath = 'item02/section02/part02';
$path = explode('/', $myPath);

$arr = &$myArray;
foreach($path as $key)
{
    $arr = &$arr[$key];
}

$arr = "somethingElse";

var_dump($myArray);
```

First turn the `$myPath` string into an `array` of keys using `explode`.

This uses a simple loop `foreach` loop to loop over the array using keys, and then by passing the values by reference it replaces the deepest value. [Demo Here](https://eval.in/875285)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work in the demo. I've tried it in my code now, and it seems to work as well! The odd thing is, I tried this before as well, but it kept overriding the entire array. I'm curious as to what the difference is. I'll look into that after wrapping this up.